# How to scrape data from webpage without inspect function?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all data from the link below. 
http://aeroportos.weebly.com/fuel-prices.html#.W7JVkWj7Sbi

However, it seems like there is no option to perform right click, inspect & then us BeautifulSoup...

Any tricks on how to deal with this?

Example on data I would like to scrape (for all rows)
So i'm trying to create an output with in the rows all locations, and columns all prices / codes / ... 
[image]
Many thanks!
Sibren

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site you can make a right click on the option that are on the top for selection of menu, and then drag down to div. Then from this div you can extract your required elements or you can copy your xpath.

Comment: Many thanks Yawar! 
However I've still not got it figured out... Updated my question to clarify a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the blue "Home" tab. You will be able to click "inspect"

Comment: Many thanks! However I've still not got it figured out... Updated my question to clarify a bit :)